# In go, why are both the reflected value and its interface the same when printed?

Tags: go, reflection, go-reflect, gofmt

Excerpt from the [Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection):

> (Why not fmt.Println(v)? Because v is a reflect.Value; we want the
>   concrete value it holds.)

This confuses me because the following code:

```
var x float64 = 3.4
var v = reflect.ValueOf(x)

fmt.Println("value of x is:", v)
y := v.Interface().(float64) // y will have type float64.
fmt.Println("interface of value of x is:", y)
```

Prints the same output:

> value of x is: 3.4
>
> interface of value of x is: 3.4

Is it because `fmt` internally finds the concrete value for the reflected `v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case, which is documented on the [`String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.String) method of [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value). It states

> The fmt package treats Values specially. It does not call their String method implicitly but instead prints the concrete values they hold.

Comment: Oh yeah haha I skipped this part from the doc: `We call the String method explicitly because by default the fmt package digs into a reflect.Value to show the concrete value inside. The String method does not.`